# How to collect 'returns' from ANTLR grammar

Tags: java, compiler-construction, antlr

If I have a ANTLR grammar where I have rules like this with a 'returns' statement:

```
string_decl returns [Pair s] : STR id EQUAL ex=str_literal ';'{$s = new Pair($id.text, $ex.text);} ;
```

And then in my main I have code like this:

```
 Lexer lexer = new Lexer(CharStreams.fromFileName(inputFileName));
 CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
 Parser parser = new Parser(tokens);

 System.out.println(parser.program()); //prints out empty array ?
```

How do I print out a list of all of my 'returns'?

Comment: `ProgramContext` returned by `parser.program()` contains all the tree structure. Use a visitor or a listener to walk the tree and get any information you need.

Answer (score 1):

The `returns` value is modeled as member of the rule context. See if you have a `String_declContext.s` member. See also [Rule Attribute Definitions](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#rule-attribute-definitions) in the ANTLR4 documentation.